# Show on Netflix about four guys, with weird anomalies in each episode

Tags: story-identification, tv

Basically they would have an adventure each episode, with some of them including a giant eye that melted the friends' brains, and at the end of the episode, one of the friends was feeding the brains back to the friends to get their memories working again.

In another episode, they met a leprechaun that could turn into objects. They had him turn into a bucket of purple ice and a soap remote control car and he got mad because they were using him. Then a giant worm monster was attacking, so the leprechaun turned into like an Elvis character and sang so beautifully the giant creature exploded.

In each episode, randomly the guys would find a tiny TV and go “I think we found… A CARTOON” and then I’m pretty sure a tiny cartoon would play before they got back to the episode.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Was it live-action or animated? Roughly how old were the guys? And did any of them have any distinctive feature that you recall?

Comment: You said its on Netflix. Was it a Netflix original or thats just where you watched it? Also was it in English or subbed/dubbed from another language?

Comment: @LogicDictates - You feel that this question lacks distinctive features?

Comment: @Valorum - No. I was asking whether any of the _protagonists_ had any distinctive features that the OP could recall. All the question says about them as individuals is that they're "four guys." Knowing a bit more about what they look like would make this significantly easier to identify.

Comment: Like knowing that one of them was Asian, for example, or had really curly hair and jughandle ears.

Comment: Hi-5 was on Netflix and had episodes with deep-sea diving, leprechauns, and purple things. And it could be as bizarre as that show sounds.